# What is the Fourier series expansion of the $e^{-2i\pi ax}, x\in(0, 1)$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am trying to find the Fourier series of the function $f(x)=e^{-2i\pi ax}$, over the interval $(0,1)$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. As we know the Fourier series $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_ne^{2i\pi nx/T}$$
First I tried to find the Fourier coefficient $C_n$ of the function. The period $T$ of the function $f(x)$ is $1/a$. So $c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int\limits_{0}^{T}e^{-2i\pi ax}e^{-2i\pi nx/T}dx=a\int\limits_{0}^\frac{1}{a}e^{-2i\pi ax(n+1)} dx.$
but after integration, I am getting $c_n =0$. Did I understand something wrong? I do not know why I am getting my Fourier coefficient as zero.

Comment: When you use Latex, please enclose the formulas in `$...$`.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/14578.  Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The integral does not vanish if $n=-1$; in this case, $c_{-1}=a\int_0^{1/a}e^0dx=1$.

Comment: And if you want to compute the Fourier series of $f$ in the interval $(0,1)$, then $T$ must be the length of the interval, not the period of $f$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment @Gonçalo.